# Anyone Know any Java Bookmarking Site

Tags: java

Hi Anyone know good website for learning and updating for Java learning.
Is something like dotnetkicks.com same in Java.

Please let me know.?

Comment: SO has 208241 question tagged with java and 23k followers.Do you expect something more?

Comment: Between SO, the Java docs available for the API at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/ and things like O'Reilly On Java (http://onjava.com/), what more do you want?

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Answer (score 1):

Well.. in my view SO is best for it.Even you are looking for some bookmarking site.U can check www.javapins.com  that is same like dotnetkicks . It a new site for bookmarking.they are doing good. bt need to improve on content side.

other than u can check javaworld.com and many more